# Finding the limit of a function with three variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have problems finding the limit of a function with three variables. The programs that numerically calculate limits cannot handle this limit, and I am not 100% sure that this limit exists. The limit that I have to solve is the following:
\begin{equation}
\text{lim}_{(y_1, y_2, y_3) \rightarrow (1,0,0)} \frac{1-y_1}{A y_2 + B y_3}
\end{equation}
where A and B are positive constants.

Edit: another constraint that I have is:
\begin{equation}
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 1, \text{so:}  (1-y_1)=(y_2+y_3)
\end{equation}

Edit2:
All y's are bound between 0 and 1.

In my limit, $y_1$ approaches 1 from the left, and $y_2$ and $y_3$ approach 0 from the right. Does this change the existence of this limit?

Comment: What have you tried beyond giving it to programs that fail to give an answer?

Comment: @Henry I have tried using L'Hopital's rule, but I don't know how to apply it to multivariate functions. I have also tried the formal method, which leads me to think that the answer is in the order of 1/(A+B)

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist. If you take the limit along the curve $(1-x^2,x,0)$ for $x\to 0$, you get the limit must be $0$, but along the curve $(1-x,x,0)$ for, say, $x\in (-1,0]$, you get $\frac{1}{A+B}$. The limits along these curves must agree if the limit is to exist in general.

Comment: I have a question about this method where the limit is approached along a curve. What is in your case 'x' and why can you approach it with multiple functions? Could you make this clear by referring to the equation a bit more when stating the limit along curve approach?
I get the point that the limit along curves must agree for the limit to exist.

Comment: $x$ is the parameter of the curve. A curve is a function $f:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$, or to any codomain really, and so in your case it may be given as a triple of functions $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$, where $f_i:I\to\mathbb{R}$. Thus I pick a curve $f$ by picking its "coordinate" functions, and for the first one I pick $f_1(x)=1-x^2$, $f_2(x)=x$ and $f_3(x)=0$. One could also work with sequences, if that is more comfortable for you, and let $x$ vary in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: When calculating the limit, I simply substitute the coordinate functions.